# Is it possible to remove built-in custom word properties?

Tags: vba, ms-word, properties, customproperty

Is it possible to remove the built-in custom properties in word such as "checked by", "date completed" etc?

I want to create my own custom properties to fill in fields in the word document but I don't want to have to filter through the built-in custom properties to find the fields I want to fill in as is it likely some will be missed so therefore are looking for a way to remove these.

The delete button is greyed out so I'm guessing if this is an option then it will probably have to be done programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: «built-in custom properties» That's an oxymoron -either they're built-in or they're custom. If they're built-in they can't be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete custom document properties in the following way:

```
ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("CustomNumber").Delete
```

or if you need to remove all of them:

```
For Each prop In ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties 
 prop.Delete() 
Next
```